# Libgdx shader on a shaperenderer's rectangle

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to draw a 2d rectangle in the shaperenderer. That is ok. But I want to create on this rectangle a custom shader.

So I dont need texture on it, I only want a rectangle with custom shader. Is it possible? How?

My rectangle now is a gradient. I want to draw my shader on this gradient...

Comment: What do you mean with shader? Transparency, hue, brightness?

Comment: I want to manipulate the gradient with my custom fragment shader. Draw  hexagons on top of the gradient with the shader. Something like an FBO, but without an FBO. Only with a ShapeRenderer and a ShaderProgram, with a rect gradient ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShapeRenderer` class has a constructor where you can pass in your own `ShaderProgram` if you do not want to use the default. However, you cannot set the `ShaderProgram` on the fly like you can when using a `SpriteBatch` to render your stuff.

View the source of `ShapeRenderer` and `ImmediateModeRenderer20` class to see how the default shaders are applied. Then adjust to your needs an create an instance of `ShapeRenderer` with your adjusted `ShaderProgram`.

Comment: Seen while code diving: there is no constructor for ShapeRenderer with only a ShaderProgram argument. The default amount of vertices is 5000, so when creating a shaperenderer pass 5000 and the shader as the arguments.